# Error after web 8 to web 8.5 upgrade

Tags: web8.5

After upgrading from web8.1 to web 8.5 I am facing the this error at transport level at the time of publishing -

> 2017-02-08 11:59:59,816 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Creating token provider for OAuth enabled OData client
>   Exception in thread "main" com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientSocketException: Could not initiate connection to the endpoint.
>           at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:222)
>           at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.callEndpoint(BasicEndpointCaller.java:86)
>           at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.getODataResponse(DefaultODataClient.java:141)
>           at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.getEntities(DefaultODataClient.java:109)
>           at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultDiscoveryClient.doClientOperation(DefaultDiscoveryClient.java:146)
>           at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultDiscoveryClient.loadFromEndpointUrl(DefaultDiscoveryClient.java:134)
>           at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultDiscoveryClient.getCapabilities(DefaultDiscoveryClient.java:108)
>           at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultDiscoveryClient.getCapability(DefaultDiscoveryClient.java:67)
>           at com.sdl.web.client.DiscoveryClient.getCapability(DiscoveryClient.java:44)
>           at com.sdl.web.client.DiscoveryClient.getCapability(DiscoveryClient.java:32)
>           at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultDiscoveryClient.getTokenServiceCapability(DefaultDiscoveryClient.java:59)
>           at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.ODataClientProvider.getTokenServiceCapability(ODataClientProvider.java:113)
>           at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.ODataClientProvider.createTokenProvider(ODataClientProvider.java:82)
>           at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.ODataClientProvider.init(ODataClientProvider.java:58)
>           at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.ODataClientProvider.(ODataClientProvider.java:51)
>           at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.RegistrationTool.(RegistrationTool.java:46)
>           at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.Main.main(Main.java:35)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>           at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>           at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:204)

In the link
[Upgrading SDL web](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E6995D0C-804C-4399-8EB1-044E64C33A12&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E6995D0C-804C-4399-8EB1-044E64C33A12.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E6995D0C-804C-4399-8EB1-044E64C33A12) if followed these steps 
1- Upgrade Content Data Store,Upgrade Content Manager database,Upgrade Translation Manager database. 
2- installed web 8.5 CM. 
3 -Applied hotfix CD_8.1.1.2569

CMS is installed and DB have been upgraded is there anything i am missing?

I see the discovery and deployer services are getting stopped automatically.

Comment: (1) Do you see `TokenServiceUrl="http://[[yoururl]]:8082/token.svc"` in the cd_storage_conf.xml (in the ConfigRepository node)?


(2) Are you undertaking a staged upgrade or a straight-forward balls and all Web8.5? 


(3) If the former, have you applied Hotfix CD_8.1.1.2569 accordingly